# How to delay js from continuing execution until local storage is updated?

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, local-storage, spotify

I'm writing a react web app to display spotify user data. I'm using the authorization with PKCE, which means that I need to obtain an access token from the API, which I then use to make API calls for data fetching. However, when I retrieve this token from the API, I have to store it in local storage so that the token will still exists if the page refreshes. Unfortunately, when I retrieve the access token, it takes too long to update the local storage with the token, so the data fetch calls start occurring prematurely, using a null access token, which obviously doesn't work. How do I wait for the token to be saved to local storage to continue execution?

The first if statement- when the site loads and the access token hasn't been retrieved yet- is the one that causes the problem. `getAccessToken()` updates the local storage, then afterwards I update the accessToken variable to use for fetching.

If I refresh the page, the access token is recognized, and the data pull works successfully.

```
let accessToken = localStorage.getItem('access_token');
    if (!accessToken){
        getAccessToken();
    }
    else if (!verifyAccessToken(accessToken)){
        console.log("token expired")
        refreshAccessToken();
    }
    else{
        console.log("token validated")
    }
accessToken = localStorage.getItem('access_token');
```

```
async function getAccessToken(){
    (...)

    fetch('https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        body: body
    })
    .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error('HTTP status ' + response.status);
        }
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
        localStorage.setItem('access_token', data.access_token);
        localStorage.setItem('refresh_token', data.refresh_token);
        localStorage.setItem('expires_in', data.expires_in);
        accessToken = localStorage.getItem(data.accessToken);
        // Calculate the expiration time in milliseconds from the 'expires_in' value
        const expiresInMilliseconds = localStorage.getItem('expires_in') * 1000;
        // Calculate the expiration timestamp and save it in local storage
        const expirationTimestamp = Date.now() + expiresInMilliseconds;
        localStorage.setItem('expires_at', new Date(expirationTimestamp).toISOString());
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
    });

}
```

I tried making the access code check an async function, because it would allow me to await the getAccessToken method. However, since the local storage is synchronous, this didn't work. Furthermore, I tried using the useEffect hook, but was unable to get this to work-- I still wasn't able wait until storage was updated for fetching.